# Serverless Email Attachment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I am a starter in Serverless and AWS. I am actually stuck in situation. I want to attach a file when sending email via serverless. The fact is I can't find any perfect article or documentation regrading my requirement.

What I did is.

JS File.

```
exports.sendMail = async(event) =>{
    var data = {
      Destination: {
       ToAddresses: [
        "******.@gmail.com"
       ]
      },
      Message: {
       Body: {
        Html: {
         Charset: "UTF-8",
         Data: "This message body contains HTML formatting. It can, for example, contain links like this one: <a class=\"ulink\" href=\"http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide\" target=\"_blank\">Amazon SES Developer Guide</a>."
        },
        Text: {
         Charset: "UTF-8",
         Data: "This is the message body in text format."
        }
       },
       Subject: {
        Charset: "UTF-8",
        Data: "Test email"
       }
      },
      Source: "********.com",
     }

    try {
      const sendPromise = await new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01" })
      .sendEmail(data)
      .promise();
      return{
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(sendPromise)
      }
    }catch (err){
      return {
        statusCode: err.statusCode || 400,
        body: err.message || JSON.stringify(err.message)
      }
    }
}
```

What I did is to send is to send a mail. This is working as expected. But don't know where to insert the attachment section.

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [SES.sendRawEmail()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#sendRawEmail-property) API in order to send email with attachments. There are a few [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-raw-using-sdk.html) in the SES Developer guide how this can be implemented in various programming languages (currently Java, PHP, Python and Ruby). Please also read the [Sending Raw Email](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html) chapter for generic information.

Comment: Is there any article related to node JS

Comment: I have not seen any JavaScript `sendRawEmail()` example in the current version of the official AWS docs, but they evolve over time.